# How to test and debug website on older version of Safari

Tags: development, mobile-safari, web-inspector

We're trying to test and debug Safari 7. I've used the Safari dev tools to connect to a physical device and use the inspector to view the page. That works fine, but I don't have access to a physical device with Safari 7. Tools like Browser stack or saucelabs I can see the issues, but I can't debug in an emulator. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Very easy.

Get a copy of Parallels or VMware Fusion. Set up a virtual machine and install Mavericks on it. You will then have all the benefits of running Safari 7 in the original environment without having to dust the hardware.

I have Fusion, and virtual machines back to 10.5 Leopard. Also have Windows back to W98, and DOS 6 just for Duke Nukem in all it's 8-bit glory. [modern.ie](http://modern.ie/) has free downloads of ready-to-go virtual machines for all versions of MSIE.

Other things you should have:

- *lots* of disk space. Like > 250GB
- *lots* of memory. VMs don't share memory, they need their own. I have 24GB.
- a big monitor, or a second monitor.